# 'Programs hacking programs' & 'The code is hidden in tumblers'

Tags: meaning-in-context

In The Matrix Reloaded, Neo said, **"programs hacking programs".**

I don't think it is a complete sentence. What is omitted here? What does it mean? A program can hack another program or what?

Besides, Seraph said, "The code is hidden in **tumblers**. One position opens a lock. Another position opens one of these doors."

What's meant by **tumbler** here? A position can open a lock? Sounds really weird to me.

Comment: Now I know what tumblers represent. Check it out in this link. http://www.tpromo2.com/ssmag/locks/lock1a/cylinder.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> programs hacking programs

It's simply stating what he observes. I could be looking at a pond and say

> Ducks eating bread.

What's *missing* is simply something like "it's", as in :

> "It's programs hacking programs."

You could imagine a lot more around that sentence:

> Gosh, so what I am looking at here, is *programs hacking programs*!

As for the tumblers, [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tumbler) might give a clue.

> **4** A pivoted piece in a lock that holds the bolt until lifted by a key.
>   **5** An electrical switch worked by pushing a small sprung lever.

Both could apply - but seen as the Matrix deals with electronics, I'd say that maybe 5 is more likely?

If you [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tumbler+switch+&oq=tumbler+switch+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3391j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) on *tumbler switch* you may get an idea of what is meant with the **positions** it can be in.

> A position opens a lock

You would have to interpret as

> When the switch is in a certain position, a lock is opened.

Comment: The physical tumblers in a mechanical lock would be a metaphor or an analogy for what is really happening, just as the physical presence of people in the Matrix is. The exiled program known as The Keymaker would not actually make physical keys, but would be more like a "keygen" for cracking other programs.

Comment: oerkelens got general ideas correctly. However, I'd like to add some notes. In the movie, programs are entities that can think and act, just like we humans do. And programs hacking programs is what Neo observed the phenomenon that had happened in the world of the Matrix as the Oracle told him (about ghosts, angels, vampires, werewolves, and aliens, which are programs that chose to do what they weren't supposed to do). The tumblers can be interpreted as either sense (4 or 5), because inside the Matrix things are real. But what is real in the Matrix is just an illusion, a metaphor as Stan said.

Comment: I was wondering whether **programs hacking programs** referred to those exiles taking a man's shell to hide in the matrix or system assimilating those exiles. What does assimilating mean here? How does the system assimilate exiles? @Stan Rogers

Comment: http://imgt5.bdstatic.com/it/u=4274717562,3226451031&fm=15&gp=0.jpg I think those five rods in this url are the tumblers, right? @Damkerng T.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I'm sorry. That link is 403 Forbidden. However, if your image looks like [this one](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tumbler+lock), you got the right idea.

Comment: Bingo! Can you answer the other question above? I can't @ two men at the same time

Comment: I will use this [script](http://www.theforbiddenknowledge.com/the_matrix_script/index02.htm) as the reference. (It's the best I could find quick.) I think the phrase "programs hacking programs" was designed to be ambiguous in the script. However, I'd like to interpret it literally like this: "A programs" hacking "B programs" ~ group A refers to those abnormal programs (ghosts, aliens, etc.), and group B refers those behaving normally, which maintain the system to be in its normal condition. However, the system is "assimilating" these abnormal programs, so we've heard about ghosts, aliens. ...

Comment: ... The rough meaning of this "assimilating" is "taking in" or "keeping". Because the system keeps these abnormal programs, therefore, ghosts, aliens, vampires, etc. do exist in the system (the Matrix).

Comment: I had thought the system was assimilating those rogue programs into its source by deploying agents to kill them. Seems I was wrong about it. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

“Programs hacking programs” I guess are programs created to hack another programs.

Tumbler is a moving part of a locking device. One position of the tumbler unlocks, the other position locks the device.

Answer (score 0):

about the programs hacking programs:maybe theyre sentient programs that can act as a code generator for themselves and hack other programs or create viruses from their code to hack other programs thats what i imagined when he said that,this is just my opinion...

Comment: This is more of a comment on the film as a whole than on the meaning of 'tumblers', which is what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

When Seraph says one tumbler position opens a lock he means a normal key put in normal lock opens a normal door. When he says another position opens one of these doors, he means when you insert a special key, that positions the lock tumbler in just the right way, it makes the door open to a different place. A place that corresponds to the code that's been activated in the tumbler